# windows deployment services to windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2016, dhcp-server, wds, microsoft-office-2010, hyper-v-server-2016

I am currently in Computer Assisted Tech training I have difficulties for the image deployment service.

I want to deploy a Windows 10 image on HP Pro Book 650G1.
I have a Windows 10 Pro x64
For this I have set up a VM Server 2016 which includes an AD, DHCP, DNS, WDS.
And a Windows10 VM that I use as an image, for deployment.

My problem is that when starting the deployment VM the DHCP runs and does not take the image (I am well set in network boot the DHCP does not want to communicate)
The configuration of my DHCP: I have configured a new range
The configuration of the deployment service to work well I have the image of the vm in the folder''' installation image'.
I think the problem comes from the ports.

could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check all the files are avaialble on RemoteInstall folder.

After installation, the following files and folders are available in the RemoteInstall folder:

SMSBoot
- abortpxe.com > Used when no advertisement is available
- bootmgfw.efi > (available in x64 folder only)
- bootmgr.exe > In Boot order this is file 3 needed
- pxeboot.com > In Boot order this is file 2 needed
- pxeboot.n12 > Can be used to skip the second F12 requirement (!)
- wdsnbp.com > In Boot order this is file 1 needed (!)
SMSIMAGES
- Boot.xxx00001.wim (WDS x86 boot image)
- Boot.xxx00002.wim (WDS x64 boot image)
SMSTemp
- A temporary folder for updating boot images
Stores
- This is the Drivers (Metadate) store

The following outlines the download process.

1. A client is directed (by using DHCP Options or the PXE Server response) to download Wdsnbp.com
2. Wdsnbp.com validates the DHCP/PXE response packet and proceeds to download PXEBoot.com.

Note: PXEBoot.com requires the client to press the F12 key to initiate PXE boot. One can rename one of the other PXE boot files (such as pxeboot.n12) to download Wdsnbp.com to a different file.

3. PXEBoot.com downloads Bootmgr.exe and the BCD store. The BCD store must reside in a \Boot directory in the TFTP root folder. Additionally, the BCD store must be called BCD.
4. Bootmgr.exe reads the BCD operating system entries and downloads Boot.sdi and the Windows PE image (Winpe.wim).
5. Bootmgr.exe begins booting Windows PE by calling into Winload.exe within the Windows PE image.